# Where is Python exception defined?

Tags: python, exception, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using the adafruit_ble library that supports Bluetooth Low Energy on desktop computers. Suffering from a flaky connection with the target hardware, it gives me an exception, BleakError, as shown in the traceback. Now I would like to catch this error with a try statement in my code. But if I simply do that, it says the name is not defined. And it turns out that the library in question is made of many files, and efforts to search for that error are failing.

So my question: what is the simplest, quickest way to find the properly qualified name of an exception that has appeared in my traceback? Using python 3, I am running on a Mac, in case it matters.

Comment: Where is your traceback?

Answer (score 1):

I googled the error name and found a [doc page](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/client.html) with this import:

```
from bleak.exc import BleakError
```

Comment: Yes, but is there a more general strategy?  There are more where this came from.

Comment: Generally speaking you find the documentation page for the module you are using. If you can't find one online, then try calling help(module_name) to get a string doc. If there isn't one, then using googles exact phrase features to search for phrases which might appear in someone else's code on stackoverflow or github like "import BleakError" ought to do it. There is a dir() function and an inspect module which let you get an idea of how a module is structured, but I never use them.

Comment: Actually come to think of it, if the error is appearing in your console output, that means it is defined at your level of scope, so you could even call help(BleakError) and print the results of that.